# Abstraction and Encapsulation are at odds with performance - How?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I've been reading the book, "Java Concurrency in Practice", where, in the Tread Safety chapter, it is mentioned that:
"Sometimes Abstraction and Encapsulation are at odds with performance". 
I did not get this part. Can someone explain with an example, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example with threads:

The good and slow code:

```
//Several classes doing each one its thing.
public class Task1 implements Runnable { ... }
public class Task2 implements Runnable { ... }
public class Task3 implements Runnable { ... }

//Collection with runnable instances
List<Runnable> tasks = new ArrayList<Runnable>();

//A producer would have populated the list with some instances depending on some conditions
if(cond1) tasks.add(new Task1());
if(cond2) tasks.add(new Task2());
if(cond3) tasks.add(new Task3());

//Now we execute tasks without caring what do they do.
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
for(Runnable r : tasks){
    executor.execute(r);
}
```

Now the bad but fast code:

```
new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        if(cond1){
            //do task 1
        } else if(cond2){
            //do task 2
        } else if(cond3){
            //do task 3
        }
    }
}.start();
```

The first case is the best in terms of abstraction (and hence from the testing and maintenance points of view, which are the most important in professional software development). The producer and consumer are decoupled, and the consumer executor doesn't care about how the tasks are implemented. BUT tasks have to be instantiated and that means slow.

In general, creating instances is slow because managing the heap needs CPU cycles, as memory needs to be tracked and allocated or released. In Java there's the additional problem of the Garbage Collector running randomly, which might be needed to allocate extra heap if we're short on memory.
 A second slowdown comes from the function calls (the function `run` of each task must be called to do its thing). Function calling is slower than not calling at all, because there has to be a tracking of the stack, and parameter passing, etc.

The second snippet is messy and has every task payload mixed up. This is real coding horror. Moreover, it both produces and consumes tasks. However, it's going to be damn fast as no instances are created and there are no function calls as the code of each task is inlined.

You might not see my point in this code as there are only 3 task being run only once, but imagine if tasks were produced at a rate of a thousand per second. This could for instance happen in a web server processing requests, or by a plane's electronic flight instrument system processing flight instruments readings.

So it's often the case that the cleaner code is slower.

As Knuth said,

> *"Premature optimization is the root of all evil"*

Answer (score 2):

Long story short: first get it right, then improve performance afterwards.

There are times when you will jump through hoops to try and increase performance, sometimes leading to bugs or bad design. Not to mention, it's time consuming! Programming strictly with performance in mind will result in code that's hard to scale, and programming strictly with design in mind will (possibly) result in more overhead.

I guess a good way to view it is encapsulation is a form of restricting; setting limits for how something can be accessed/modified. Those restrictions can come at a price of performance.

The full quote states:

> Sometimes abstraction and encapsulation are at odds with performance — although not nearly as often as many developers believe — but it is always a good practice first to make your code right, and then make it fast